# Return array of images after content

Tags: filters, the-content

I am trying to output a bunch of images after each post but I can only output one.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'image_posts' );
function image_posts( $content ) {
    global $post;
    if ( ! $post instanceof WP_Post ) {
        return $content;
    }
    $all_images = get_images(); // array of images 
    switch ( $post->post_type ) {
        case 'page':
            // return $content; // this only return content
            foreach ($all_images as $image){
                echo '<img src="'.$image.'" />';
            }
            // return $content; // this returns all images on top of the content


        default:
            return $content;
    }
}
```

and if I modify the loop to this:

```
foreach ($all_images as $image){
   return content . '<img src="'.$image.'" />';
}
```

I only get the content with one image. How can I output all the images after the content?

Comment: What values are in the array? Have you confirmed that there are more than one set of URLs in there?

Comment: @ian, yes, in my questions, I can output all images before content if I put `return $content` after the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that we hit the switch statement and the page case and assuming that $all_images does indeed contain image urls:

In your switch statement, try storing all the images in a variable first and then concatenate them with `$content` in your return statement.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'image_posts' );
function image_posts( $content ) {
    global $post;
    if ( ! $post instanceof WP_Post ) {
        return $content; // If this is true, we return $content and the rest of the code doesn't run.
    }
    $all_images = get_images(); // array of images 
    $images = ""; // We'll store all our image tag strings here here. Assuming, of course, we make it to this section of code.

    switch ( $post->post_type ) {
        case 'page':
            foreach ($all_images as $image){
                $images .= '<img src="'.$image.'" />';
            }
            return $content  . $images; // Concatenate $images after $content
    default:
        return $content;
    }
}
```

Part of the problem you are likely running into is that once you return `$content` no other code in the filter will run.

For added bonus, you can add a class to your image tag or wrap it with a div or some other wrapper to do some css magic later :)

A point of clarification on WordPress filters and actions: WP filters and actions work best with `return` statements in order to function properly. While you *could* `echo` something, that `echo` actually takes place at the point of code execution. This means that you often end up with your code showing up at the head of the page.

Comment: `Part of the problem you are likely running into is that once you return $content no other code in the filter will run.` in my filter or for all filters?

Comment: So this is a scope thing. The return statement takes place within the scope of the `image_posts` function alone which is triggered by the `the_content` filter. So when we return anything, that essentially ends all code within the current scope. So in this case, it will end all code execution within that function alone, but all other code on your website will continue to run as expected :)

Comment: I asked a related question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/262484/has-shortcode-for-content-added-after-the-content can you please look at that one too?

Comment: I'd be happy to :)