# has_shortcode for content added after the content

Tags: shortcode, the-content

I added some shortcode after the content using filter, like this:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'image_posts' );
```

but now that I run `has_shortcode` in another function, this returns false even though the shortcode is there (which was added using the above filter.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'gallery_style');
function gallery_style(){
  if ( has_shortcode( $content, 'gallery' ) ) {
     // enqueue style
     // it fails for posts which add gallery using the_content
  }
```

how can I test the `has_shortcode` for contents added using add_filter?

Comment: Can you post the full function/code where your `has_content` conditional check exists? Is it in another `the_content` filter?

Comment: no it is a `add_action( 'wp_head'`, I want to add the style where post has gallery shortcode.

Comment: `wp_head` action hook runs before `the_content` filter hook.

Comment: @Fayaz can the order be changed?

Comment: Nope. `wp_head` loads the HTML content within `<head>` part of HTML, and `the_content` filters content within `<body>`, so that can't be changed. However, if you edit your question and  provide the full CODE of those functions with explanation of what you want to do, we may suggest a different approach that works.

Comment: @Fayaz I want to check the content to see if it has gallery shortcode to load a style. The `add_action( 'wp_head', gallery_style) ` just enqueue a style inside the `has_shortcode`

Comment: I got that, but why do you add shortcode in `the_content` filter hook function? What's the CODE of that function?

Answer (score 1):

For this, you'll actually want to utilize the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action instead of `wp_head`.

`wp_enqueue_scripts` is technically the proper way to add scripts and styles to your site. This action allows us to both register scripts and styles for later use (which is what we want here) and allows us to output scripts and styles to our page without hard coding. Also this matters because `wp_head` runs before `the_content` which means that you won't be able to modify the head once your code gets to `the_content`.

First let's register our style using the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action.

```
/**
 * Register the gallery stylesheet for later use if our content contains the gallery shortcode.
 */
function enqueue_gallery_style(){
        wp_register_style('gallery_style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/gallery.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_gallery_style'); // register with the wp_enqueue_scripts action
```

We register the script using the `wp_register_style` function. In this case we'll make use of the first two parameters. The first is the name we want to give to the style so we can use it later. You can name it whatever you want. Here I've named it "gallery_style". The second parameter is the url path to the stylesheet in your theme or plugin (make sure to update based on your specific path). Here are more details on [wp_register_style](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style)

Now we can add another `the_content` filter in addition to your `image_posts` filter to perform the shortcode conditional check. Inside the check, if we find it, then we run the `wp_enqueue_style` function to enqueue our gallery style and add it to that specific page.

```
/**
 * This function is used to check the_content to see if it contains any shortcodes
 *
 * @param $content
 *
 * @return string
 */

function shortcode_check( $content ) {

    if ( has_shortcode( $content, 'gallery' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'gallery_style' ); // this is the same name we gave our gallery style when we registered it.
    }

    return $content; // Make sure you still return your content or else nothing will display.
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_check' );
```

More info on [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)

**Method if you are trying to add admin-generated styles (eg. from customizer or other settings) that won't have a physical file.**

If you need to output styles that are generated via the admin (ie, colors) you can utilize the `wp_add_inline_style` function.

This function will allow you to add on styles to a registered stylesheet.
So in the case of our already registered gallery.css file above, we can add
`wp_add_inline_style( 'gallery_style', $user_css );` and it will add that as an inline style immediately after registered stylesheet.

Here `$user_css` would be the styles as a string **without** the `<style>` wrapper.

So in your case, you could register a stylesheet for gallery with some base styles and then use this function to add styles that would override those base styles.

```
function shortcode_check( $content ) {
    if ( has_shortcode( $content, 'gallery' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style('gallery_style');
        wp_add_inline_style( 'gallery_style', $user_css ); // this will add our inline styles. Make sure to sanitize!!!
    }

    return $content; // Make sure you still return your content or else nothing will display.
}
```

More on [wp_add_inline_style](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style)

Comment: thanks for in depth answer, I have some constraints and **must** use wp_head to insert the style

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Why exactly do you have to use wp_head? There may be another way around the constraints ;)

Comment: user sets custom colors

Comment: Ok, so then the user-set styles are actually dynamic and not in a file, is that correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct. I tried [this method](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style) and I had some issues so I had to go with wp_head option

Comment: Got it, check my edit. I added an additional way to do it without `wp_head` so you can add those styles.

Comment: Ha, just saw you posted about `wp_add_inline_style` too. Hopefully my explanation will help with that. The key there is that you have to tack on the styles to some sort of registered stylesheet that exists, even if it's an empty one.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually enqueue styles and scripts from any hook. If `wp_head()` had already fired, then the styles and/or scripts will be enqueued into the footer.

```
//* Add filter to the_content
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_262484_the_content' );
function wpse_262484_the_content( $content ) {

  //* Maybe do something useful with $content

  //* Enqueue style if the content has gallery shortcode
  //* Since wp_head() has already fired, this will be output in the footer
  if ( has_shortcode( $content, 'gallery' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpse-262484', PATH_TO . 'style.css' );
  }
  return $content;
}
```

Comment: the statement inside has_shortcode never gets executed. I added a shortcode to the content using `the_content` filter and now no matter where I run `has_shortcode` it fails

Comment: Then the content doesn't have the gallery shortcode. Make sure this filter is run after the one inserting the shortcode.